# Jquery post and get data from PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Jquery code looks like:

```
$('#gal').rating('gl.php?gal_no=<?=$gal_no;?>&id=<?=$id;?>', {maxvalue:10,increment:.5, curvalue: <?=$cur;?>});
```

PHP code:

```
$br=mysql_query("SELECT count(gal) as total FROM ...")
if ... {
echo '0';
}
else echo '1';
}
```

Jquery code successfully transmitted data to PHP script and when the PHP done with checking data echo the result ('1' or '0'). 
How can I get this PHP result back to Jquery and based on them write a message?
Some thing like:

```
if(data=="1")
{
$("#error").show("fast").html('not correct').css({'background-color' : '#F5F5F5','border-color' : '#F69'});
}else{
$("#error").show("fast").html('correct').css({'background-color' : '#FFF','border-color' : '#3b5998'}); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havent shown your full code for the rating plugin so i dont know where you want to make your ajax call at, but that call should look something like this:

```
$.post('gl.php', {
  data: {
     gal_no: '<?=$gal_no;?>',
     id: '<?=$id;?>'
  },
  function(data) {
    if(parseInt(data) == 1) {
      $("#error").show("fast").html('not correct').css({'background-color' : '#F5F5F5','border-color' : '#F69'});

    } else {
      $("#error").show("fast").html('correct').css({'background-color' : '#FFF','border-color' : '#3b5998'}); 
    }
  }
});
```